# Validación de un registro de un campo en php

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una simple comprobación si existe el mismo email en mi base de datos pero siempre me sale que esta disponible, el código es este:

```
$usuario = ($_REQUEST["email"]);

$consulta = mysql_query("select * from sys_usuarios where email = '$usuario'");
    if( mysql_num_rows($consulta) == 0){

         if($msiLink->query("insert into sys_usuarios (nombre,telefono,email,clave) values ('" . trim($_REQUEST["nombre"]) . "','" . trim($_REQUEST["telefono"]) . "','" . trim($_REQUEST["email"]) . "','" . trim($_REQUEST["clave"]) . "')")){
        echo "Se ha registrado satisfactoriamente!.";
    }
    else{
        die("Error al grabar los datos: " . $msiLink->mysqli_error);
        }    
   }
   else{
        echo "El email ya esta registrado con otro usuario, ingresa otro";
   }
```

Comment: ¿El código te da un error? ¿De dónde sale `$msiLink` y qué tiene asignado? Deberías tratar de sanitizar el dato a fin de evitar SQL Injection. Te sugiero veas esta [pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php).

Comment: Es una variable para ejecución de consultas, pero de una u otra forma no funciona.

Comment: Si agregas el error que obtienes en la ejecución puede ser más fácil identificar donde está el fallo. Cuanta más información proveas en tu pregunta, es más probable que alguien pueda ayudarte.
¿Qué tipo de variable es `$msiLink`? ¿Es una instancia de una clase propia? ¿Es una instancia de una clase de la librería PDO o mysqli? Cuanta más información proveas en tu pregunta, es más probable que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Nada en el código tiene la cadena "está disponible", cómo es posible que ese código diga que "está disponible", no lo sé, pero ya que el código produce mensajes, sería mejor que dijeras qué mensaje produce para hacernos una idea de por dónde va la ejecución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estas haciendo las consultas de una manera correcta, es por ello que no te salta ningún tipo de error.

```
$consulta = mysql_query("select * from sys_usuarios where email = '$usuario'");
```

Debería de ser:

```
$consulta = $msiLink->query("select * from sys_usuarios where email = '$usuario'");
```

Si no existe el correo en la base de datos no es necesario utilizar una condicional.

```
if( mysql_num_rows($consulta) == 0){
  $msiLink->query("insert into sys_usuarios (nombre,telefono,email,clave) values ('" . trim($_REQUEST["nombre"]) . "','" . trim($_REQUEST["telefono"]) . "','" . trim($_REQUEST["email"]) . "','" . trim($_REQUEST["clave"]) . "')"){
  echo "Se ha registrado satisfactoriamente!.";
}
```

Sin embargo, si sigue sin funcionarte, te dejo un ejemplo similar a lo que estás tratando de lograr, quizás pueda servirte de guía para lo que estas haciendo :)

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    //Como tu quieres utilizar el método POST, lo haremos de la siguiente manera. 
    //La variable $_SERVER es una variable reservada que incluye cierta información del propio servidor. 
    //Lo que quiere decir que el 'metodo de peticion' (REQUEST_METHOD) se utilizara solo SI la peticion es mediante POST.
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
         $correo = $_POST["correo"];

         //Procederemos a hacer una consulta que buscara el correo del usuario
         $buscarCorreo = "SELECT * from usuarios WHERE correo='$correo'";

         //Realizamos la consulta y anadimos $connection, ya que es la variable que creamos en nuestro archivo connection.php
         $resultado = $connection->query($buscarCorreo);

         //Usaremos la funcion mysqli_num_rows en la consulta $resultado,
         //esta funcion nos regresa el numero de filas en el resultado
         $contador = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

         //SI SI EXISTE una fila, quiere decir QUE SI ESTA EL CORREO EN LA BASE DE DATOS
         if($contador == 1) {
            echo 'El correo ya existe';
         } else {
         echo 'El correo no existe';
         }
    }
?>
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda estoy para apoyarte, saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu Query esta bien en realidad deberia funcionar, si ejecutas ese Query directamente en Mysql funciona? es decir has probado ejecutar el `SELECT` y el `INSERT` desde la consola del Mysql sin ningun error? Pueden estar sucediendo 2 cosas, o hay un error en el `INSERT` y por ese motivo siempre dice que esta disponible, o quizas sea el `SELECT`, prueba y nos avisas por favor.

Cuando un Query no funcione desde PHP y no logres dar con el problema intenta ejecutarlo desde la consola de Mysql.

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado :) por si alguien mas le sirve probé con esto:


    if ($_REQUEST["tipo"] == "registrarUsuario") {
        $email = trim($_REQUEST["email"]);
        $query  = $msiLink->query("select * from sys_usuarios where email = '$email'");
        $row    = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        $rows   = $query->num_rows;
        if($rows > 0){
            echo "El email fue usado en otro usuario, por favor intente con otro";
        }
        else{
******query para insertar datos******
    }